# PostgreSQL replication slot - how to see standby nodes

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I am using PostgreSQL 11.2. I have replication slots setup. I am able to commit to a table and see it on the standby. I have few more standbys. How can I see from the master what other standbys I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting from `pg_stat_replication`. `client_addr` will be the IP address of a standby.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query and check for client_addr, client_port, and client_hostname.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_replication;
```